# Cauchy-Lipschitz-Picard theorem in Banach spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, banach-spaces

In his famous book, just before proving Hille-Yosida theorem, Brezis gives a generalization of the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem for existence and unicity in Banach spaces, which I will call $E$. At the beginning he states that the space $$X= \left\lbrace u \in C\bigl([0, \infty);E\bigr) \mid \sup_{t \geq 0} e^{-kt} \|u(t)\| < \infty \right\rbrace$$ is a Banach space for every fixed $k$.

Now, I take a Cauchy sequence in $X$ which I call $\{u_n\}$. Then $\forall \epsilon >0$ it exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|u_n-u_m\|_X < \epsilon$ if $n,m \geq N$. Then I can prove that for every fixed $t_0$ in $[0,\infty)$ I have that $\{u_n(t_0)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $E$, because I can just take $\epsilon '=\epsilon e^{-kt_0}$ and then use some trivial estimates to prove that $\|u_n(t_0) - u_m(t_0)\| < \epsilon$ for $n,m$ big enough. The problem is that if I now define $u(t)= \lim_{n\to \infty} u_n(t)$ I don't know how to prove it is continuous. Indeed I would estimate $\|u(t)-u(t_0)\|$ with $$\|u(t)-u_n(t)\|+\|u_n(t)-u_n(t_0)\|+\|u_n(t_0)-u(t_0)\|$$
But from here I don't know how to continue, because I would need for instamce that $\forall n>M$ $\|u_n(t)-u_n(t_0)\|\leq \epsilon$, but with only punctual convergence I should not be able to conclude. Maybe it is very simple and I am missing some trivial fact, but I don't see it right now.

Comment: The norm in $X$ is $\sup_{t\ge 0} e^{-kt}\lVert u(t)\rVert$. That exponential factor should do the trick

Comment: Yeah, Ideally I would like to say that given $\epsilon >0$ there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $||u_n(t)-u_m(t)||<\epsilon$ if $n,m >N$ for all $t\geq 0$. The problem is that taking a Cauchy sequence in $X$ and not in $E$, the best I can prove is that fixing $t_0$ I have $$\sup_{t}e^{-kt}||u_n(t) - u_m(t)|| < \epsilon e^{-kt_0}$$ where $n,m$ depend on the $t_0$ chosen. Then the sup is $\leq$ then the function valued in $t_0$ and I conclude. The main problem is that I don't know how to obtain something more useful, indipendent with respect to the chosen $t$.

Comment: I think that if you fix $M>0$ and $t_0\in [0, M]$, then you should obtain uniform estimates in $[0, M]$ which allow you to conclude that $u$ is a continuous for $t\in [0, M].$ And since $M$ is arbitrary, $u$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: Since the sup would be a max for Weierstrass, right? Then I can take $t_0$ as the point of max and conclude.

Comment: Or maybe defining $\epsilon$ in a more useful way